# Handling Browser authentication when parsing

Tags: java, swing, basic-authentication

I am currently working on a link validation script which uses `HTTPURLCONNECTION` to connect to the servers. But some of the servers have browser authentication, which invariably causes 401 errors. The major problem over here is that there are multiple authentication credentials and it would be useful I can extract the string displayed in the authentication dialog box so that I can enter the correct credentials.

If this is not possible programatically, could you please guide me as to how I can display the Pop Up's to the user itself and get the credentials manually and then continue with the link validation.(I have seen Xenu Link Sleuth do this). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks